# Regex to match optional character in any order

Tags: c#, regex

I need to be able to match strings like:

`GQG6VJ6K`, `TYTU-TIDM-56`, `4-5-P-Z`, etc.

The hyphen `-` is optional, but there must be at least one alphanumeric character.

So far the best attempt I have come up with is `[A-Z0-9-]+` which wrongly matches a single hyphen.

I also tried `(?[-]*)(?[A-Z0-9]+)` but it doesn't work (I'm a regex noob). Bonus points for why.

What's the solution?

**EDIT:**

@archeong87 led me to my final solution: `^[A-Z0-9]+(-{0,1}[A-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: What programming language and/or environment you use?

Comment: Do you want to allow strings such as `-abc` or `abc-`, where hyphen is first or last character of the string?

Comment: The final solution you posted does not permit hyphens at the start or end of the string. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Your final expression: `^[A-Z0-9]+(-{0,1}[A-Z0-9]+)*$` has a major problem - it can result in [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) when presented with a non-matching string. To fix, you need to make the dash required inside the repeated group like so: `^[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: @ridgerunner The dash is optional. Will this regex still respect that requirement?

Comment: @Kryptonite - Yes. The dash is inside a `(-...)*` group that is applied _zero or more times_. I would say that zero times is pretty much optional!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close!

```
^(?=.*[A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9-]+$
||             |         |
||             |         anchor your regex
||             |
||             what you were already doing
||
|lookahead assertion: at least 1 alphanumeric
|
anchor your regex
```

**EDIT:**

While thinking about how to exclude `-` being at the beginning or the end, I realized there was a much simpler solution:

```
^[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*$
```

It looks like @AndreKR had this idea, so +1 to him.

Comment: Seems to work, but why are you using a dot; doesn't that match any character?

Comment: Good question. Yes, the ``.`` matches any character, because basically we just want to say that _somewhere_, regardless _where_, there is an alphanumeric character. The second half already enforces that only ``[A-Z0-9-]`` can be used, so there's no need to re-enforce that condition; thus ``.`` is used as short-hand.

Comment: This doesn't match >1 consectuive character - e.g.: PP. What about ^[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*$ ?

Comment: I have slightly modified your latest EDIT to get what I need. Everyone gave excellent answers so it was hard to choose, but you were the first to write an explanation of your proposed answer.

Comment: @acheong87 You edited version is complete wrong. It even does not match `AA`

Comment: Yes, I have noted that above. I don't know who to award the answer to but I think I learned the most from @archeong87

Comment: @xdazz - Thanks for pointing it out. I was honestly expecting the accepted answer to go to @AndreKR's or someone else, so I wasn't as insistent upon testing as I should have been regardless. It was a careless mistake, leaving out the ``+``s. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
([A-Z0-9]-?)*[A-Z0-9]
```

Comment: `^([A-Z0-9]+-?)+$` is probably better to ensure the entire string matches this pattern.  It will wrongly (maybe?) also match `ABC-` though

Comment: @ThomSmith - this solution is wrong, it wouldn't match `abc-` for example.

Comment: The original post implied that this was correct, and the OP's stated final answer is equivalent to this one. The contradictory comment was not posted until after this answer was submitted and downvoted.

Comment: @ThomSmith - Original post: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1d93ab02-bc83-4d37-9e71-4d76dfbd937e/view-source - show me where it implied...

Comment: The requirements were stated vaguely: "like" a set of strings. None of the given strings violated this expression, and hyphens-as-delimiters are sufficiently common that it's not an unreasonable guess based on the given incomplete specification. Obviously, the OP should have specified one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern

```
^[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]*$
 └───┬───┘ └───┬──┘└───┬───┘
     │         │       └ alphanumeric characters or hyphens (none or any)
     │         │
     │         └ one alphanumeric character
     │
     └ alphanumeric characters or hyphens (none or any)
```

or

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9-]*$).*[^-]
    └───┬───┘     └─┬┘
        │           └ non-hyphen
        │
        └ allowed characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z\d])[a-z\d-]*$/i
```

`i` means case insensitive, if you only want upper case, then

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z\d])[A-Z\d-]*$/
```

Comment: Tell me difference between `^(?=[A-Z\d-]*[A-Z\d])[A-Z\d-]*$` and `^(?=.*[A-Z\d])[A-Z\d-]*$`

Comment: @Ωmega Good point, you're right, should just use `.` instead.